# Copy/paste dates exactly as displayed? Not necessarily the format, but as they're displayed visually

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out how to overwrite my date with what's being **displayed**.

For example, what's being displayed is `06/01/2016`, but the actual data behind that is showing `01/06/2016`.  The date I want to have in there is June 1, 2016 (which is what's displayed).  Changing the format of the cell doesn't help, because I'm doing some formulas with the Dates later, so actually need to have Excel have the correct date.

I have about 10,000 of such dates, where the *displayed* date is exactly what I want to have, but the actual formula "reversed".

Essentially, I would love to just copy that column (or run a sub) that puts what the cell literally *displays* into the cell.

[image]

What sort of works is doing this, but it only works on those cells with "backwards" dates...essentially passing the day as a month, and month as a day.

`=DATE(YEAR(C1),DAY(C1),MONTH(C1))`.

It "falls apart" though when the date is actually correct and I don't want it to change:

[image]

So, what'd be best is to just literally overwrite the cell with what's displayed.

Or, what would an `IF` statement be that I could use to somehow check if the date *displayed* is what I want, and if so keep that, otherwise use that `=DATE(YEAR(),DAY(),MONTH())` "trick"?

I also tried `=IF(DAY(C2)>12,DATE(YEAR(C2),DAY(C2),MONTH(C2)),C2)` but that doesn't work either because it returns `June 01 2016` for both `01/06/2016` and `06/01/2016`.

I may be overlooking something simple, I've been staring at this for an hour or so...Any thoughts/ideas are appreciated!

Comment: What's your default date format, and how are you populating these dates on the sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll check the default date format but I believe it's set to something not standard (like Azerbaijan or something...), I'm getting the dates from a PDF I exported as an Excel file.

Comment: Hmm I tried copy pasting some data here for y'all, but I just kept the format as displayed...so it's certainly a formatting issue. But also gave me the idea - maybe it's just quickest to copy the column, paste in a txt file, then copy back in to a brand new worksheet.

Comment: How does the title of the question relate to the question?  If it is because you have generated that column from stuff that you put in a dictionary, maybe it would be better to correct the code creating the dictionary entries rather than trying to fudge something to correct the final results.

Comment: @YowE3K - AH! I was working on a Python question the other day, but figured it out...so when I came to post this question my draft was still there, but I totally forgot to change the title. Sorry for the confusion! :P   (but +1 for offering a solution! :D )

Comment: @BruceWayne - I hadn't even noticed that you were the OP!  (I'm so used to there being two groups of SO people - the askers and the answerers - and it seems weird seeing an answerer as an asker :D)

Comment: @YowE3K  haha I know, it's weird (yet fun in a way) when I do have a question... Especially because I think I know the answer deep down but haven't figured it out :P  ...but honestly it shows how great folks are at SE for teaching me enough to where I seldom have questions! +1 for everyone!

Comment: have you tried to use something like: `range.value = cdate(range.text)` for those cells which have `if range.numberformat = "dd/mm/yyyy" then`... at least: the wrong cells all have also the wrong formatting ;)

Comment: @TimWilliams - Just checked, the Formatting is a Date, with Armenian Locale, dd/mm/yyyy for the "wrong" ones. For correct ones it's English (Carribbean), mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @DirkReichel - That'd would do it too! I didn't check at the time that *all* dates were *not* dd/mm/yyyy, but was a mix. Checking for the format first and doing the `cdate(rng.text)` works too.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say wee have dates in column **C** from **C1** through **C100** that appear to be correct. *(so if you see 06/12/2017 you want it to be June 12<sup>th</sup> and not December 6<sup>th</sup>)*

Try this short macro:

```
Sub dateFixer()
    Dim ary(1 To 100) As String
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set rng = Range("C1:C100")

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        ary(i) = r.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    rng.Clear
    rng.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = ary(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Ooh, yeah that works nicely! I like it too because it clears the range and formatting, uses an array, and is quick.  This way I don't have to copy/paste all my data to a new WB.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A really clean solution is to use the CELL() function.

`=CELL("format",A1)` will return `"D1"` for cells formatted as d/m/y, and `"D4"` for cells formatted m/d/y. So, with this you can conditionally flip month and day:

```
=IF(CELL("format",A2)="D1",DATE(YEAR(A2),DAY(A2),MONTH(A2)),A2)
```

[image: screen capture demonstrating the formula]

Comment: Nice call using the `cell("format")` option. This works too, but I have thousands and thousands of rows to check, and it's a huge sheet already, so it takes a while to update everything...just fyi why I went with Gary's solution.  But again, this works, thanks!

Comment: No hurt feelings :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Text` property of a range returns the display text: "what the cell literally displays."

Note that literal is the right word - for example, if your column is too narrow, `Text` will return the displayed `#####` characters instead of any useful value.

The `Text` property will not return an array, so you'll have to loop through your range and read/write individual cells with something like this:

```
For Each c in rng
    c.Value = c.Text
Next c
```

Incidentally, the documentation on this property is almost nonexistent. [This blog post](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) goes into a more detailed review of the property and how it relates to `Value` and `Value2`.

Comment: Thanks too for this! I'll have to remember that in the future. Appreciate it!